Angular17 hosting project presents this error: ReferenceError: caches is not defined
I made a project using the MapTiler library. And when putting the project on the hosting service, the error appears:
ReferenceError: caches is not defined
    at main-FAGKM46X.js:584:229302
    at Generator.next (\<anonymous\>)
    at main-FAGKM46X.js:584:228898
    at new t (polyfills-RT5I6R6G.js:2:2236)
    at xp (main-FAGKM46X.js:584:228718)
    at UT (main-FAGKM46X.js:584:229256)
    at main-FAGKM46X.js:584:230307
    at Generator.next (\<anonymous\>)
    at main-FAGKM46X.js:584:228898
    at new t (polyfills-RT5I6R6G.js:2:2236)


With this error, the map style does not load either.
The program accesses an API that takes the current location of the ISS and shows it on the map
Component HTML
<div class="map-container">
    <div class="info-container" >
        <span>Latitude: {{locateISS?.iss_position?.latitude}}</span>
        <span>Longitude: {{locateISS?.iss_position?.longitude}}</span>
        <span>Velocidade: {{speed}}km/h</span>
    </div>

    <div class="map-wrap">
        <div class="map" #map></div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon" #icon></div>
</div>

Component TS
    import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, NgZone, OnDestroy, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID, ViewChild, inject, signal } from '@angular/core';    
    import { IssService } from '../../../services/iss.service';
    import { Map, MapStyle, config, Marker, Popup} from '@maptiler/sdk';
    import '@maptiler/sdk/dist/maptiler-sdk.css';
    import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
    import { LocateISS } from '../models/locate.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-iss-map',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [],
      templateUrl: './iss-map.component.html',
      styleUrl: './iss-map.component.scss' 
    })
    export class IssMapComponent  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy{

      map?:Map
      private issService = inject(IssService)
      locateISS?:LocateISS
      issIcon:any
      speed:Number = 0
      marker:any
      isBrowser = signal(false);
      platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID)

      @ViewChild('map')
      private mapContainer!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

      @ViewChild('icon')
      private elementIcon!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  
      constructor(){
        this.isBrowser.set(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
        if(this.isBrowser())
          inject(NgZone).runOutsideAngular(() => {
            setInterval(() => this.updateMarker(), 1000);
          })
      }
  
      ngOnInit(): void {
        config.apiKey = 'wGRvHdO3WKYFTWYfoxL5'
        this.issService.getLocate().subscribe(locate => this.locateISS = locate)  
    
      }
  
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.map = new Map({
          container: this.mapContainer.nativeElement,
          style: MapStyle.STREETS,
          center: [ Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.longitude), Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude)],
          zoom: 2
        });
        this.issIcon = new Marker({element : this.elementIcon.nativeElement})
        .setLngLat([Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.longitude!), Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude!)])
        .setPopup(new Popup().setHTML("<span style='color:black; padding:20px;'>ISS</span>"))
        .addTo(this.map!); 
      }
  
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.map?.remove();
      }
  
      updateMarker(){
       const oldLat = this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude
        const oldLong = this.locateISS?.iss_position.longitude
        this.issService.getLocate().subscribe(locate => this.locateISS = locate)
        let distance = 60 * 1.1515 * (180/Math.PI) * Math.acos(
          Math.sin(Number(oldLat) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) + 
          Math.cos(Number(oldLat) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos(Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * 
          Math.cos(Number(oldLong) - Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.longitude) * (Math.PI/180))
        );
        this.speed = Math.round(distance * 1.609344)
        this.issIcon.setLngLat([Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.long`), Number(this.locateISS?.iss_position.latitude)])    
      }
    }

I thought it might be something when building the project, I built it again and it didn't work

What version of the SDK are you using? Try updating to the latest version 2.0.3. The cache option was introduced in version 2 and in one of the first versions there was a bug.
The other option you can try to see if it works is to disable the cache.
maptilersdk.config.caching = false;

I have tested your code with the latest version of the SDK and angular 18 (without the service of obtaining the position of the ISS - I have simulated it) and it has worked for me
